# List View with Fragment and TabLayout(TabSwiper)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Question that i used Listview in tabswiper with fragment. I have 5 tabs.In first Tab Listview is there. If i click on one item of that listview than it replace with another fragment which has listview in same tab.I set first listview in 1st tab.when i clicked any item than it shows blank page.

What i do?

Comment: show some code, please.

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide some effort showing your code , and check that link for better questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i will put code as soon as possible.